# OpenCV Face recognition Java code terminates JVM

Tags: java, opencv, image-recognition, face-recognition

I have the following code for detecting faces in an image using [`OpenCV`](https://opencv.org/) taken and adapted from [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/68037/opencv-3-java-face-recognition-example-requested/):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread;
import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imwrite;
import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.rectangle;

public class FaceRecognizer
{
    @Test
    public void recognizeFace() throws IOException
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        // Create a face detector from the cascade file in the resources directory.
        ClassPathResource classifierResource = new ClassPathResource("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(classifierResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("lena.png");
        Mat image = imread(classPathResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());

        // Detect faces in the image.
        // MatOfRect is a special container class for Rect.
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

        // Draw a bounding box around each face.
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray())
        {
            rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        // Save the visualized detection.
        String filename = "faceDetection.png";
        System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        imwrite(filename, image);
        //FaceRecognizer fr;//= new LBPHFaceRecognizer();
    }
}
```

When I run it, it terminates the `JVM` early:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

This happens at the

```
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
```

line.

The image I used is the following (it's a well known example image):

[image]

Also the `lbpcascade_frontalface.xml` file is part of the [`OpenCV` release pack](https://opencv.org/releases.html).

Why does it crash? Is there something wrong with the code? I use `OpenCV` `3.4.1` and other `OpenCV` code samples work.